# When yielding a tuple, why does typescript union the types of both indices?

Tags: typescript, destructuring, for-of-loop

I am yielding an array with values of type `[number, object]` from a generator function and iterating over the function through `for...of` loop. When destructuring the values using `for (const [k, v] of iterator())` the type of `v` is `number | object`. I expected it to have the type `object`- same as the one I used in the `yield` of the generator function.

I have created a demo of the problem I'm facing in the typescript REPL [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/BQMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjjApgJwIYeASmQG8AoZc5caeJAKlQxxgUwOLIs4Bt0ZUATAFzIIYALYAjLMgC8yAAwBuDp3JQkAZz4A3bFzDphpVSeTZhoyVgA0K0+QkXxUzHc4BfWe3udzyAIy2PhSOyABMbhTuyvYA7gAWcDzIwHD8yAA8AfKExsHIAJ5w6FzpANqRwWlB+Zy6+uiVqgC6yk2cacgA1HL+MabudoN2ICwp6hBayGUA1tbI2s3ICCAMWLgsBLlNExoIPAB0XAgA5sBzCwfY+P3kg+74BIpAA)

The problem is in line number 22 where typescript compiler complains about accessing a key that possibly does not exist after destructuring.

Why does typescript think that the destructured variables could be of either of the types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a generator issue. Array literals are usually widened to array types. If you use a `as const` assertion to preserve the tuple type it works as expected

```
(function iterate() {
    function* iterator() {
        let id: number = 0;
        const value: {
            a: number,
            b: number
        } = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        };
        while (id < 10) {
            yield [
                id,
                value
            ] as const;

            id += 1;
        }
    }

    for (const [k, v] of iterator()) {
        console.log(k, v.a);
    }
})();
```